# route handlers is not working in next.js 13.2 and return error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, frontend

I want to create api in my website like /api/popular-movie
this is my file structure
[image]

and this is route.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import Redis from "ioredis";
type Result = {
  data: string;
  type: string;
  latency: number;
};

let redis = new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL as string);

export async function GET() {
  let start = Date.now();
  const cacheKey = "popular_movies";
  let cache = await redis.get(cacheKey);
  cache = JSON.parse(cache as string);
  let result: Partial<Result> = {};
  if (cache) {
    console.log("loading from cache");
    result.data = cache;
    result.type = "redis";
    result.latency = Date.now() - start;
    return NextResponse.json(result);
  } else {
    console.log("loading from api");
    start = Date.now();
    return fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY}&page=1`
    )
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((data) => {
        result.data = data;
        result.type = "api";
        result.latency = Date.now() - start;
        redis.set(cacheKey, JSON.stringify(result.data), "EX", 60);
        return NextResponse.json(result);
      });
  }
}
```

but when I want to fetch data from /api/popular-movie I got error

> TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/popular-movie
> at Object.fetch (D:\nextjs-project\full-stack-project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:26686)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async getData (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/page.tsx:14:17)
> at async Home (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/page.tsx:21:18) {   [cause]:
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)

and this is my request:

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(`/api/popular-movie`);

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res.json();
}
```

I do not know when I go to localhost:3000/api/popular-movie it tells me the page has not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `api` from a page that is in another folder like `pages/somepage/pageThatYouCall` you have to route the `api` like this:

```
../api/theApiPage
```

Comment: no I am calling it in http request with fetch, I do not want to import this

Comment: There is no import, you have to so this:
`const res = await fetch(`../api/popular-movie`);`

Answer (score 0):

it might be bacause you are on windows and your folder separator is backslash `\` instead of forward slask `/`. check this out [next-config-js/trailingSlash](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/trailingSlash)

> Open next.config.js and add the trailingSlash config:
>
> ```
> next.config.js
>
> module.exports = {
>   trailingSlash: true,
> };
> ```

Comment: I tried this but has not been solved.
in page route every things work fine but when I migrate to app route my api is not working and and when I go to api url I got page not found !

Comment: Can you share your github repo or create a codebase with reproducible error

Comment: it was solved when upgrade v 13.2 to version 13.4